# animation glitches after build apk in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Run Animations work well in the unity Editor but after build android apk that glitches and not play properly.

I have tried that solution but not work at all please help

1. Edit > Project Settings > Quality, the "Blend Weights" option was set      to "2 Bone", I upped it to "4 Bones"
2. create again animation controller and apply animation on player but still not working

[before creating apk player look and animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjzek.png)

[after creating apk player fingers shape change and animation glitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzbI9.jpg)

Comment: Posting images in editor and android will be helpful

Comment: Unity Version please?